# Check object type in Rails controller before calling method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I'm wondering if there is a more object-oriented way to accomplish what I'm doing.  A controller in my app has a 'vote' method, which allows a user to cast an up or down vote on a resource. In order for a resource to gain voting functionality, it has to include one of two modules: `Votable` or `DistrictVotable`.

The `DistrictVotable` module means that you need to specify a district when voting. With the `Votable` module, that is not the case, you can vote without a district.

So, here is what the relevant part of my controller method looks like:

```
def vote
  @resource = find_resource
  vote_type = params[:vote_type].to_i

  if @resource.is_a? DistrictVotable
    @resource.vote(district, vote_type, current_user)
  elsif @resource.is_a? Votable
    @resource.vote(vote_type, current_user)
  end
end
```

To me, it seems less than ideal that the controller needs to check the `@resource` type before calling `vote`, but I can't figure out away around this since that determines whether or not a `district` needs to be passed in.

This `vote` method is added to the controller by a `VotableController` module. Maybe I need to create a separate `DistrictVotableController` so the type check won't be needed?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the vote method accept arbitrary number of arguments. One way to do it is:

In Votable module:

```
def vote(args)
  user = args.fetch(:user)
  vote_type = args.fetch(:vote_type)
  # some logic
end
```

In DistrictVotable module:

```
def vote(args)
  user = args.fetch(:user)
  vote_type = args.fetch(:vote_type)
  district = args.fetch(:district)
  # some logic
end
```

And you call it with

```
@resource.vote(user: current_user, vote_type: params[:vote_type], district: district)
```

The district parameter will be ignored in the Votable module.